# What is the relation between the Biological oxygen demand and the depth of water tank?

Tags: civil-engineering, environmental-engineering, waste-water-treatment

I need a relation between Biological oxygen demand and depth.

The ultimate [BOD] is known, and I need to calculate a [BOD] at any depth of water tank; temperature is constant. The tank is two meters deep and the incubation lasts seven days.

Ultimate biological oxygen demand is 0.05 mg/L.

I need constant-rate equations for deoxygenation and biological oxygen demand.

Comment: Your question is in danger of being closed because it's unclear what you're asking.  Please add some more detail and show your work for the result you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Please be more specific about the system or process you're concerned with; "water tank" is vague. What is the incubation period? What is the maximum depth of your tank? If you tell us more about the problem you're trying to solve, it will be easier for us to give a useful answer.

Comment: I will add more informations...